# Generic Delegate across different UIWebViews

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I need one generic delegate that handles most of my events for different webviews.

I created a delegate:

`@interface GenericWebViewDelegate : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate>`

And inside viewDidLoad I set:

`GenericWebViewDelegate* genericWebViewDelegate = [[GenericWebViewDelegate alloc] init];`

[TheWebView setDelegate:genericWebViewDelegate];

The above is returning EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Any ideas?

Comment: please, provide more code, it is not enough to say any sure thing.

Comment: Could you report the exact line where it crashes? is it the assignment to `TheWebView` or the call to the delegate method?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from your question, it is either of two possible things.

1. if your app crashes when doing the assignment to `TheWebView`, then it means that `TheWebView` has been deallocated before; so possibly you should review the way you create it.
2. If it happens when the delegate method is called, the it depends on how you create your delegate object. The way you define your delegate, it won't survive long after the execution of `viewDidLoad`, so when it is called, the app crash.

   What you need to do is storing the delegate in a `strong` property of your class. In that way, it will live as long as your class instance, and possibly be still there when it is called.

Comment: Thanks Sergio, basically I added a delegate inside the view and stored the reference there.

The only issue I had was to access view methods, so I decided that the best way forward is to create a utilities class with all these methods.